# How to authenticate PHP backend in iOS Swift with one user?

Tags: php, ios, swift, authentication

I am building an iOS iPad app for one user. The app communicates with an PHP backend to handle the HTTP requests. How do I make sure that its the iPad app sending the HTTP requests and not an anonymous request?

Do I need to pass something through the header of HTTP request or do I need to build a tokening service using OAuth?

Bit confusing as there will only be one user off the app.

Comment: Depends on the sensitivity of the content. You could use HTTP Basic Auth with HTTPS if the data isn't critical. The question is quite broad, there are lots of options depending on your data, resources, etc.

Comment: Data is Personal information